# Nodemailer getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Error

Tags: node.js, email, dns, smtp, nodemailer

Looking for some insight into this error I'm getting.

> on smtpTransport.sendmail(func(err, info){})

The err variable returns this:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.gmail.com smtp.gmail.com:465
       at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

and my code is:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'xxx'
                }
            });
            var mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
                text: ' '
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
    });
```

Answer (score 19):

Try stop using gmail service and set it up like any other smtpTransport like the following.

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});
```

If This does not work, your server might not be able to lookup smtp.gmail.com due to a firewall or something, to check type the following.

```
 nslookup smtp.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue because I wrote the wrong spelling of

> stmp.gmail.com

it should be

> smtp.gmail.com

```
var transport = mailer.createTransport({
    port : 465,
    host:'smtp.gmail.com',
})
```

Comment: I see... I'm trying to help you to better understand the rules of this site. As is, you have high probability of having a downvote... Because in the original question, clearly, the error report says: `ENOTFOUND smtp.gmail.com smtp.gmail.com:465`. Anyway, do what you think is right! For next answers, try to be more accurate, reading carefully the question. Great answers help the whole community!

Comment: thankyou i made a same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error with aws ses service. In my case it was wrong configuration credentials.

```
AWS_SES_REGION="us-east-2"
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID=""
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=""
```

I updated the AWS_SES_REGION then it worked for me

Comment: Could you be more explicit with how you have fix, this is not really in answer.